# Makefile:649: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-18.04

I've read an checked out all the answers to the same kind of error I seem to have. After implementing the solutions of adding a tab here or there as suggested and checking for spaces I cannot seem to get the makefile working.

This comes from the makefile of MDM display manager (https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm) after configuring via my machine by running:

```
./authogen.sh --with-prefetch
./configure
```

now I fail on `make`

Here's a sample of the makefile that I'm having some issues with:
This code sample is a sample after loading in vim then running `:set list` to view tabs as stated earlier in another makefile missing separator issue.

Supposedly error occurs on line 649.

```
635 $
636 cscopelist-am: $(am__tagged_files)$
637 ^Ilist='$(am__tagged_files)'; \$
638 ^Icase "$(srcdir)" in \$
639 ^I  [\\/]* | ?:[\\/]*) sdir="$(srcdir)" ;; \$
640 ^I  *) sdir=$(subdir)/$(srcdir) ;; \$
641 ^Iesac; \$
642 ^Ifor i in $$list; do \$
643 ^I  if test -f "$$i"; then \$
644 ^I    echo "$(subdir)/$$i"; \$
645 ^I  else \$
646 ^I    echo "$$sdir/$$i"; \$
647 ^I  fi; \$
648 ^Idone >> $(top_builddir)/cscope.files$
649 $
650 distclean-tags: $
651 ^I-rm -f TAGS ID GTAGS GRTAGS GSYMS GPATH tags$
652 ^I-rm -f cscope.out cscope.in.out cscope.po.out cscope.files$
653 $
654 distdir: $(DISTFILES)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Makefile:649: *** missing separator. Stop

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/knudfl/tmp/mdm/docs'
Makefile:651: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Plenty of Makefile´s in mdm. Edit the mdm/docs/Makefile from

```
.PRECIOUS: Makefile

@YELP_HELP_RULES@
```

.... The separator is a [TAB], not 8 times space : Edit to ... `[TAB]@YELP_HELP_RULES@`

```
.PRECIOUS: Makefile

    @YELP_HELP_RULES@
```

---

EDIT : See the answer by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk

Comment: Thanks solved the issue of the first round of make. Time to debug some more permissions issues!

Comment: This is *not* a solution. There is no bug in this `Makefile`, you just need to have `yelp-tools` on your system that comes with `/usr/share/aclocal/yelp.m4` that has a definition of `YELP_HELP_RULES`.

Comment: You have to re-run `./autogen.sh` after installing `yelp-tools`.

Comment: after doing this I was able to successfully build a package for mdm, so it worked for me. There was no need for yelp-tools in my install

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `yelp-tools` before running `./autogen.sh`.  After doing
that you'll notice that `@YELP_HELP_RULES@` in `docs/Makefile` is just a placeholder that
should be expanded.